# How to add 2 decimal values and add it into the new column of a DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to add 2 decimal values and save it to a new datacolumn. But i realize its not how i should do it. Where am i thinking wrong, Please let me know. Thank you! This is in Visual Studio 2005 using c#..

```
 Dataset ds = new DataSet();
 DataColumn newColumn2;
 newColumn2 = new DataColumn("TotalAmount");
 decimal TotalAmountSold = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     TotalAmountSold = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AmountSold"]) + Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AmountUpgraded"]);
 }
 TotalAmountSold = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(TotalAmountSold.ToString()), 2);
 newColumn2.Expression = TotalAmountSold.ToString();
 ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(newColumn2);
```

Comment: are you using sql code to return data and populate `dataset`? You can do this in sql query. In C# you may have to create new `datatable` with extra column and loop original and add row with calculated column to new `datatable`.

Comment: @rs. Yeah, i am using SQl but the stored procedure is too complex for me, so i thought i should try adding up in c#.

Comment: in sql you can just do `CAST(AmountSold As decimal(10,2) + CAST(AmountUpgraded As decimal(10,2) As TotalAmountSold`

Comment: Please tell me this is some sort of legacy code or a very small (borderline throw away) program.  Otherwise it would be inadvisable to use DataSets instead of an ORM like EF or NHibernate.

Comment: isnull(sum(cast(RDC.AmountSold as numeric(10,2))), 0) and isnull (sum(cast(RDC.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2))), 0) are the values. I was missing syntax all the way to add them. Can we add these, @rs.??

Comment: @R0MANARMY I am just learning sql and c# and this is one example given by a friend to practice on. I have no idea what is ORM like EF or Nhibernate? If you advice me to learn what it is, please say so. i will take time to know what you are saying! :-)

Comment: ORM stands for Object Relational Mapper.  Two of the most popular ones in .NET are NHibernat and Entity Framework.  There's a guide to getting started with NHibernate [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/08/29/nhibernate-3-beginners-guide-published.aspx) and a mult-ipart guide [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/tags/WPF/default.aspx).  The multi-part guide uses a WPF application as an example, but a lot of the concepts will apply to other types of projects.

Comment: An introduction to Entity Framework can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B).  There's a lot to learn there, so I would say pick one and start reading and experimenting with it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  You basically want to create a column, specify the formula and then add that column to a DataTable.  You'll end up with something like

```
// Create total column.
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
totalColumn.ColumnName = "total";
totalColumn.Expression = "AmountSold + AmountUpgraded";

// Add columns to DataTable.
...
table.Columns.Add(totalColumn);
```

You don't need to manually loop through all of the rows, that will be computed for you.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted! I was n't sure about setting the datatype to column. This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help; however, the documentation page was literally the first result when you google "DataTable formula column."  You should really take time to look through MSDN, there are a lot of great examples there.  If you don't understand some of them, you could ask for an explanation here.  That is more likely to result in answers that will be helpful in a wider range of situations.

Comment: Sure, i will look into whatever you are advising me. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just learning? Some advise:

1. Get rid of visual studio 2005. Microsoft offers a free, albeit limited, version of it's latest Visual Studio. Mostly because VS 2005 is so crappy.
2. Find and use the microsoft online documentation.
3. Get a better example. You are missing a significant piece - the fetching of the data from the database. Google "C# DataAdapter class".
4. Converting to decimal is probably unnecessary. I *assume* the database is storing the numbers as a numeric data type. I further *assume* the DataTable that receives this data has the particular columns specifying their datatype as decimal.

That said here's how the code you show can clean up:

```
    DataColumn newColumn2 = new DataColumn("TotalAmount", typeof(decimal));
    decimal TotalAmountSold = 0;

    foreach(DataRow theRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
        TotalAmountSold += theRow['AmountSold"] + theRow["AmountUpgraded"];
    }
```

1. DataColumn constructor that takes the type. Now we don't have to convert anything during addition.  This ASSUMES the columns being added are also decimal.
2. foreach is cleaner and more expressive than the for loop
3. +=     Or else `TotalAmountSold` gets over written for every row we are adding.

Comment: Good catch on VS 2005, didn't even notice that in the question.  Unless you are using typed datasets, whatever comes out of `theRow["..."]` will be `object` and you'll have to cast it before you can perform math operations on it.